# Is tempered an adjective here?

Tags: sentence-construction

Consider this expression

> Were the documents you received **legitimate** or were they **tempered**?

Legitimate here is definitively adjective, but I am not sure if tempered here has been used as an adjective or used in the passive form. Which of the two forms is correct?

Comment: The first "Were" should be "Was".

Comment: I think perhaps you mean "tampered (with)" - that is, illicitly modified - rather than "tempered", which can be a process applied to steel or glass, or a description of a person's emotional makeup, e.g. bad-tempered, even-tempered, &c.  So a native American speaker would write "Were the documents legitimate, or had they been tampered with?"

Comment: The 'with' is not optional when the meaning is 'alter surreptitiously'.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up two similar verbs, to temper sth and to tamper with sth.
"or were they tampered (with)": You can interpret tampered. as adjective or as passive.